# Get int variables within a String method Java

Tags: java, methods

This is homework. Just going to put that out there. I feel it is best to show my code first and explain what I'm attempting to do

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Question1 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int length, odd, even, largest;
    int n = getNumber();
    length=odd=even=largest=initialize();
    String sequence=createSequence(n, largest, odd, even, length);
    displaySequence(sequence);
    displayStatistics(largest, length, odd, even);
}
private static int getNumber(){
   Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter the value of the number: ");
   int number = kb.nextInt();
   return number;
}
private static int initialize(){
    return 0;
}
public static String createSequence(int n, int largest, int odd, int even, int length){
    String sequence="";
    sequence+=n+" ";
    while (n!=1){
        n = (n%2==0) ? n/2 : 3*n+1;
        System.out.print(", "+n);
        sequence+=n+" ";
        if(n%2==0){ even++;
        }else{ odd++;}
        if(n>=largest){ largest = n;
        }
        length++;
    }
    return sequence;
}
private static void displaySequence(String sequence){
    System.out.println(sequence);
}
public static String displayStatistics(int length, int even, int odd, int largest){
    String nil = "";
    System.out.println("The largest number in the sequence was "+largest);
    System.out.println("The length of the sequence was "+length);
    System.out.println("There were "+odd+" odd numbers");
    System.out.println("There were "+even+" even numbers");
    return nil;
}

}
```

I need attempting to display the largest number in the sequence, the length of the sequence, how many even numbers there were in the sequence and how many odd numbers there were in the sequence. But since I cannot return an int value in the createSequence method, I cannot get the new values for each statistic. Preventing me from displaying said statistics. How would I access these new variables to be used in the final method?

Note:

Requirements:

1. Declare variables in main
2. Initialize variables in Initialize()
3. createSequence (Create the sequence)
4. displaySequence (Then display the sequence in a separate method)
5. finally displayStatistics i.e. length, evens, odds, largest (in its own method), this is the one that's troubling me

Comment: Instead of returning a String type, you can return an array of 4 variable.

Comment: To add on @LuaiGhunim's comment, the array could be an array of 5 strings, where `arr[0]` is your sequence, `arr[1]`-`arr[4]` are the 4 integer values you want but as strings, then when you get the array back, to get integers from your strings do `Integer.parseInt(arr[1])` etc.

Comment: @DavyM method worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try reimplementing your code off of my basecode

```
public class Question{

    public class NumberStats {
        int len;
        boolean isOdd;
    }

    private ArrayList<NumberStats> stats = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Question q = new Question();
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String number = "";
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a series of numbers or q to quit: ");
            number = kb.next();
            q.stats.add(q.parseNumber(number));
        } while (number.equals("q")==false);

        q.printSummary();


    }

    private void printSummary(){
        int oddCount = 0;
        int evenCount = 0;
        int longestNumber = 0;

        for (NumberStats s : stats){
            if (longestNumber<s.len){
                longestNumber = s.len;
            }
            if (s.isOdd){
                oddCount+=1;
            } else {
                evenCount+=1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("Longest number length was : %i, Odd Numbers: %i, Even Numbers: %i",longestNumber,oddCount,evenCount));
    }
    private NumberStats parseNumber(String number){
        NumberStats stats = new NumberStats();
        Integer lastNumber = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number.charAt(number.length()));
        stats.isOdd = true;
        if (lastNumber%2==0){
            stats.isOdd = false;
        }
        stats.len = number.length();
        return stats;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher may be a bit more impressed if you created a Sequence class.  The class attributes would be the stats (which could be accessed via getter methods).  The createSequence method would become the constructor.  And you could implement a toString method to return a string representation of the contents.